# how does copy.copy() works in python?

Tags: python, copy

I have tried this below scenario in shell.

```
import copy
a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
cp = copy.copy(a)
a.append(6)
print a # [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6]
print cp # [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
```

why is a and cp not the same when copy supposedly creates a reference?
while this another scenario works as expected.

```
a[2].append(11)
print a # [1, 2, [3, 4, 11], 5, 6]
print cp # [1, 2, [3, 4, 11], 5]
```

what is the logic behind the difference?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html):

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.

So after copying `cp` points to a *new* list object, but `cp[2]` is still a *reference* to the list `a[2]`. You can verify this using the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
>>> cp = copy.copy(a)
>>> id(a) == id(cp)
False
>>> id(a[2]) == id(cp[2])
True
```

Compare to `deepcopy()`:

```
>>> cp2 = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> id(a) == id(cp2)
False
>>> id(a[2]) == id(cp2[2])
False
```